# Gmail API only returing 1Mb of data

Tags: python, gmail-api

I've filtered all the messages I want to request into a label in Gmail and I'm successfully getting mail back by using this bit of code in their quickstart.py script:

```
# My Code
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds = '{Label_id}', maxResults='10000000').execute()
messages = results.get('messages', [])

for message in messages:
    msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id'], format='metadata', metadataHeaders=['subject']).execute()
    print(msg['snippet'].encode('utf-8').strip())
```

I first listed all the labels, and their ids, in an earlier request, and substitute that in where it says {Label_id}. And then I ask for just the subject metadata field. The problem is that the response only ever returns exactly 1 Mb of data. I know this because I redirect the output into a file and do an `ls -latr --block-size=MB`. Moreover, I can see there are way more (older) messages in that label than what it's returning based on the dates. The request always stops at exactly the same message. None of them have any attachment.

Per their API reference I should be allowed:

```
Daily Usage 1,000,000,000 quota units per day

Per User Rate Limit 250 quota units per user per second
```

I don't think that's what I'm hitting but maybe I'm wrong because each message has 1-3 replies to it which I can see coming in and perhaps those are counting as 5 quota units per? Not sure. I've tried playing with the `maxResults` parameter but that hasn't seemed to change anything.

Am I hitting a cap here, or is it in my request logic?

**EDIT 1**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
import base64
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

## If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    messageArray = []
    pageToken = None
    while True:
        results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds = '{Label_ID}', maxResults=500, pageToken=pageToken).execute()
        messages = results.get('messages', [])
        for message in messages:
            msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id'], format='metadata', metadataHeaders=['subject']).execute()
            messageArray.append(msg)
        pageToken = results.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if not pageToken:
            print('[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, messageArray)))
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EDIT 2**

This is the final script that I went with. This one spits out a much nicer and cleaner format that I just redirect to a file and is easy to parse.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
import base64
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

## If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    pageToken = None
    while True:
        results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds = '{Label_ID}', maxResults=500, pageToken=pageToken).execute()
        messages = results.get('messages', [])
        for message in messages:
            msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id'], format='metadata', metadataHeaders=['subject']).execute()
            print(msg['snippet'].encode('utf-8').strip())
        pageToken = results.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if not pageToken:
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxResults` max value is 500. If you set it higher you'll still only get 500 messages in the results. You can confirm this with a len check of `messages`.

You need to implement [pagination](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/pagination).

```
messages = []
pageToken = None
while True:
  results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds = '{Label_id}', maxResults=500, pageToken=pageToken).execute()
  messages.append(results.get(messages, []))
  pageToken = results.get('nextPageToken', None)
  if not pageToken:
    break
```

If you just want the raw unparsed email message try using

```
# at top of file
from base64 import urlsafe_b64decode

msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id'], format='raw').execute()
print(urlsafe_b64decode(msg['raw']))
```

Comment: Well that certainly pulls back a lot more data (10 MB now) but the base64 encoding doesn't seem to decode properly/fully. I just ran `cat messages.txt | base64 --decode` but it only decodes a very small snippet before saying "invalid input". I used sed to replace "-" and "_" with "+" and "/" respectively but that didn't change anything. Is it the metadata format that is limiting me then?

Comment: forgot about the b64 decode. It's URL safe base64 so some characters are subbed out.

Comment: No worries. This did the trick for me `print(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(msg['raw'].encode('utf-8').strip()))`. Otherwise I was getting a TypeError. So...I still only get emails as far back as I was with the metaData format. April 9, 2018 is the oldest it will go back, despite there being emails as old as 2015 in that label. So this tells me its definitely not a data cap/limit. Perhaps mail after 1 yr and ~2 months gets archived or ignored? I don't get any errors. I don't understand why the request just stops.

Comment: see my edits to answer above (and would appreciate an upvote/answered if you feel it's correct). You are only seeing the first 500 results likely.

Comment: ahh ok ok. I'll implement this and give it shot real quick.

Comment: Ok that definitely did the trick. I'm seeing emails from 2015 now. I made an edit to my original post with the new code that is getting everything back. It gives some pretty gnarly output right- I'm sure there's a more elegant way to parse it. But nothing some basic linux text processing commands can't sift through.

Comment: Ok I cleaned it up a bit. THANK YOU so much for your help. Really amazing. :)